# Unexpected elements being spliced out of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some javascript ([here's](http://jsfiddle.net/261xvLf1/) the JSFiddle)

```
var array = new Array();
array.push('a');
array.push('b');
var index = array.indexOf('b');
array = array.splice(index, 1); // splice out the element
alert(array[0]); // Which one is left?
```

I would expect that the alert box will return 'a' because 'b' is being removed, however the dialog is showing 'b'.

Similarly if I try to remove 'a'

```
var array = new Array();
array.push('a');
array.push('b');
var index = array.indexOf('a');
array = array.splice(index, 1); // splice out the element
alert(array[0]);
```

Then 'a' is returned.

Why are (what I believe to be) incorrect values being spliced out of the array?

I'm using chrome if that helps.

Comment: Remove the `array =` part from `array = array.splice(index, 1);` and it will return the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MDN docs on [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> Returns
>
> An array containing the removed elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

`splice()` is not a "remove" function. The `splice()` method changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.
This means that the actual *array itself* is changed.

To remove an item from an array, you should use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'stringToRemove', 'c'];
var filtered = array.filter(function(element){
    return element !== 'stringToRemove';
});
alert(JSON.stringify(filtered))
```

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus, I must have used that function dozens of times without issue, I could sport what was wrong! Obvious when someone points it out!

Comment: @Liath: Yea, sometimes, all we need is a little reminder ;-) Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
array = array.splice(index, 1); // splice out the element
```

do this,

```
array.splice(index,1);
```

Because the method returns an array of spliced out items which is replacing your modified array.